# How to have a python script print out the exact match in a txt file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting, python-3.8

I have a python script that takes user input, then searches a txt file and prints the line. However, when the user inputs a number that is apart of other numbers it will print out everything in relation.

For example, if the user inputs STT1, but there is another line thats called STT12, 13, 14 etc. The script prints out each line since it has the number 1 in it. How would do I make the script only print out the exact match?

Example Output

```
Please enter your area: TTT17
Please enter STT name: STT1



STT Location:

TTT17 | STT1 | Floor 1 | Row 2 | Section 2




STT Location:

TTT17 | STT13 | Floor 1 | Row 22 | Section 2




STT Location:

TTT17 | STT14 | Floor 1 | Row 22 | Section 2




STT Location:

TTT17 | STT17 | Floor 1 | Row 42 | Section 2




STT Location:

TTT17 | STT18 | Floor 1 | Row 42 | Section 2
```

Example Code

```
def find_stt():
  with open('{}'.format(db_file), 'r') as f:
    find_flag = False
    for line in f.readlines():
      if line.startswith(area) and name in line:
        print("\n" + "\n" + "\n" + color.BOLD + "STT Location:" + color.END +
              "\n" + "\n" + color.BOLD + ' '.join(line.split()) + color.END + "\n")
        find_flag = True
    if not find_flag:
      failed_search()
```

Comment: Add a space to either side of the search term before searching. Or concatenate the two before searching `'TTT17' + ' | ' + 'STT1'`.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking with `name in line`. This condition will be true for all the substrings that contain `name`. Using regular expression will be a solution for this.

```
if line.startswith(area) and re.search(r'\b'+ name + r'\b', line)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I imported RE and added line to my code, if line.startswith(area) and re.search(name, line):   However, it's still doing the same thing, printing out everything that has that number in it

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. May not be the best way, but it works. Basically I took my input variable,

```
name = input("Please enter STT name: ").upper()
```

and created a new variable with it adding a space at the end

```
name_search = name + " "

def find_stt():
  with open("{}".format(db_file), "r") as f:
    find_flag = False
    for line in f.readlines():
      if line.startswith(area) and name_search in line:
        print("\n" + "\n" + "\n" + color.BOLD + "SPP Location:" + color.END +
              "\n" + "\n" + color.BOLD + " ".join(line.split()) + color.END +
              "\n")
        find_flag = True
    if not find_flag:
      failed_search()
```

This resolved my issue.